# Java copy files into zip with Files

Tags: java, file-copying

How do I copy a file from `D:\test\` folder to `D:\test.zip` using `java.nio.files.Files`? I got `NoSuchFileException: D:\Ausbildungsnachweise\Ausbildungsnachweis_Technisch_Form.doc -> D:\test.zip\Ausbildungsnachweis_Technisch_Form.doc` as exception. I think i am using the right pathes, but no idea why this error occurs, since the paths do exist.

My whole method:

```
Map<String, String> env = Collections.singletonMap("create", "true");
Path dir = Paths.get(destinationFolder.getAbsolutePath());
Path destination = dir.resolve(zipNameGenerator.getName() + fileEnding);
URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + destination.toUri());

try {
    FileSystem fs;
    if (overwriteZipWithSameName || !Files.exists(destination)) {
        fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
    } else {
        fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri);
    }
    for (String file : sourceFolder.list(filenameFilter)) {
        Files.copy(sourceFolder.toPath().resolve(file), fs.getPath(file));
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you try changing file:/D:/test.zip to file://D://test.zip    . Just 2 cents

Comment: Why don't you use ZipEntry?

Comment: @DavidBrossard it's a matter of personal preference, but I find the zip FileSystem easier to use than ZipEntry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URI uri = new URI("jar:file:/D:/test.zip");
```

No, it should be `jar:file:///D:/test.zip`. But the most portable way of doing it is:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("D:\\");
Path file = dir.resolve("test.zip");
URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + file.toUri());
```

Similarly, where you do:

```
Paths.get(sourceFolder + "\\" + file)
```

it's more portable to do:

```
sourceFolder.resolve(file)
```

(for example, if you run the application on Linux in the future, the "\" won't work.)

Also, you could make your map more succinctly like this:

```
Map<String, String> env = Collections.singletonMap("create", "true");
```

**UPDATE:**

Following your updated code and your comment below, I've created a working main class, shown below, reusing as much of your existing code as possible while correcting where necessary. Note that you need to use `newFileSystem()` even for existing zip files. The `getFileSystem()` call assumes you've already created a `FileSystem` object somewhere else in your code, which is cached by the file system provider, and `FileSystems.getFileSystem()` returns a reference to the already existing object. Also, FileSystem is Closeable, so use it in a try-with-resources statement.

Complete class, fully working:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class SOQn47577298 {
    private final static Map<String, String> CREATE_TRUE =
            Collections.singletonMap("create", "true");

    interface ZipNameGenerator {
        String getName();
    }

    static void copyFileToZip(
            File sourceFolder,
            FilenameFilter filenameFilter,
            File destinationFolder,
            ZipNameGenerator zipNameGenerator,
            String fileEnding,
            boolean overwriteZipWithSameName) throws IOException {

        Path dir = Paths.get(destinationFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        Path destination = dir.resolve(zipNameGenerator.getName() + fileEnding);
        URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + destination.toUri());

        final Map<String, String> env;
        if (overwriteZipWithSameName || !Files.exists(destination)) {
            env = CREATE_TRUE;
        } else {
            env = Collections.emptyMap();
        }

        try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)){
            for (String file : sourceFolder.list(filenameFilter)) {
                Path source = sourceFolder.toPath().resolve(file);
                Path dest = fs.getPath(file);
                Files.copy(source, dest);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final File source = new File("D:\\Ausbildungsnachweise");
        final FilenameFilter nameFilter = (dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".doc");
        final File dest = new File("D:\\");
        final ZipNameGenerator zipNameGnr = () -> "test";
        final String fileEnding = ".zip";
        final boolean overwrite = false;

        copyFileToZip(source, nameFilter, dest, zipNameGnr, fileEnding, overwrite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips, really appreciate it. Sadly I can't create a file from the `URI uri`. It throws `IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`. I need the file of my destination to check if the file already exists or if i need a new one

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that shouldn't be a problem. Where do you get this error? Is it when you call `Files.exists(uri)`? You shouldn't be passing a uri to Files.exists; just pass a Path (without the jar: in front).

Comment: Okay, now it properly creates a new zip file if none exists, but I also need to open existing zip files. If I try that, it throws  `FileSystemNotFoundException` on `fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri);`. Also my copying doesn't do anything. (updated code)

Comment: Could you maybe give a working example of copying files?  with `Files.copy(sourceFolder.toPath().resolve(file), new File(destination.resolve(file).toString()).toPath());` i get this exception `NoSuchFileException: D:\Ausbildungsnachweise\Ausbildungsnachweis_Technisch_Form.doc -> D:\test.zip\Ausbildungsnachweis_Technisch_Form.doc`. Source file exists and desination directory exists too.

Comment: Did my updated code (including the self-contained demo application class) work for you?

Comment: I used another way now (`ZipOutputStream`) to accomplish this task. Still thanks for the update and the code as well. It might help others (or me) to use `FileSystem` properly